# Create view for a child-master relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an entity called Entity, (lol).

```
        public class Entidad
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Propiedad> Propiedades { get; set; }
}
```

I also have an entity called Properties

```
 public class Propiedad
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Entidad Entidad { get; set; }

        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string TipoDeDatos { get; set; }
    }
```

My Create view with the automated scaffolding gets rendered like this
http://screencast.com/t/aNU4tEH8EA1

However, I should be able to select the Entity from a dropdown list.

this is the automatically generated view

```
@model Inspinia_MVC5.Areas.GlobalAdmin.Models.Propiedad

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Areas/GlobalAdmin/Views/Shared/_LayoutGlobalAdmin.cshtml";
}

<div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h2>Create</h2>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("List", "Index")
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <strong>Create</strong>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="title-action">
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary"})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                <div class="ibox-title">
                    <h5>Create Propiedad</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="ibox-content">

                @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Codigo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Codigo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Codigo)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoDeDatos, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TipoDeDatos)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoDeDatos)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-white"})
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Questions is how can I add the dropdown and make it fill the values from the entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that automatically.

You'll need to add a DropDownList to your View and add every entity you want to be selectable to this dropdown.

On the post, query for the entity, and then create Add the properties to it.

Also, check your controller, the default behavior for MVC is to create a child entity controller receiving the parent (in this case 'Entidad') id, make it receive only the model for semantics since you're not 'Entidad' specific in this case.

Comment: as this is my first time I try to do that, can you be more explicitly with code samples?

Comment: The following link gives you a step-by-step to do that... http://www.splatfx.com/adding-dropdown-comboboxes-in-mvc-views